# React Component array not updating

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning react, and I'm stuck with not updating list components.
The component shows all of the list elements that I add manually, but not rendering any changes.

I searched a lot for solutions.
All of my change handlers are binded, the setState inside handleSubmit should update ClockRow...

My App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Clock from './Clock';
import ClockRow from './ClockRow';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {items: [], tle: 'Teszt', ival: 200};

        this.handleChangeTitle = this.handleChangeTitle.bind(this);
        this.handleChangeInterval = this.handleChangeInterval.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChangeTitle(event) {
        this.setState({tle: event.target.value});
    }

    handleChangeInterval(event) {
        this.setState({ival: event.target.value});
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        if(this.state.tle.length > 0 && this.state.ival > 9){
            this.setState({items: [...this.state.items, <Clock interval={this.state.ival} title={this.state.tle} />]});
        }

        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="row">
                    <h1 className="col text-center">Hello, React!</h1>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <label>
                            Title: <input type="text" name="tle" value={this.state.tle} onChange={this.handleChangeTitle} />
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            Interval: <input type="number" name="ival" value={this.state.ival} onChange={this.handleChangeInterval} />
                        </label>
                        <input type="submit" value="Add"  />
                    </form>
                </div>
                <ClockRow clockItems={this.state.items} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

My ClockRow.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ClockRow extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {clocks: props.clockItems.map((x, i) => <div className="col" key={i}>{x}</div>) }
    }

    render(){
        return(<div className="row">{this.state.clocks}</div>
    )};
}

export default ClockRow;
```

My Clock.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Card, CardTitle, CardBody, CardFooter} from 'reactstrap';

class Clock extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {counter: 0, interval: parseInt(props.interval), title: props.title};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.timerID = setInterval(() => this.tick(), this.state.interval);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.timerID);
    }

    tick() {
        this.setState((state) => ({
            counter: state.counter + 1
        }));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Card>
                <CardTitle>{this.state.title}</CardTitle>
                <CardBody>{this.state.counter}</CardBody>
                <CardFooter>{this.state.interval}</CardFooter>
            </Card>
        );
    }
  }

  export default Clock;
```

Comment: Put regular data in your component state and derive the JSX from that data in the render method. You generally don't want to store `React.createElement` results in your state. If you take props and add it to your state, the state will not update when the props update. It's therefore a good idea to just use the props directly if you can, and the component will keep itself updated automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/zxlzzv05n3

- ClockRow.js is surplus
- Clock.js is not changed
- App.js is changed, and "React styled":

  ```
  import React, { Component } from "react";
  import Clock from "./Clock";

  class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { items: [], inputTle: "Teszt", inputIval: 200 };
    }

    handleChangeTitle = event => {
      this.setState({ inputTle: event.target.value });
    };

    handleChangeInterval = event => {
      this.setState({ inputIval: event.target.value });
    };

    handleSubmit = event => {
      console.log(this.state);

      if (this.state.inputTle.length > 0 && this.state.inputIval > 9) {
        this.setState(prevState => {
          return {
            items: [
              ...prevState.items,
              {
                title: this.state.inputTle,
                interval: this.state.inputIval
              }
            ]
          };
        });
      }

      event.preventDefault();
    };

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="row">
            <h1 className="col text-center">Hello, React!</h1>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <label>
                Title:{" "}
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="tle"
                  value={this.state.inputTle}
                  onChange={this.handleChangeTitle}
                />
              </label>
              <label>
                Interval:{" "}
                <input
                  type="number"
                  name="ival"
                  value={this.state.inputIval}
                  onChange={this.handleChangeInterval}
                />
              </label>
              <input type="submit" value="Add" />
            </form>
          </div>

          <div className="row">
            {this.state.items.map((item, index) => (
              <div className="col" key={index}>
                <Clock {...item} />
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  export default App;
  ```